# Is it possible to get city, county, country from postal code using Google Places API?

Tags: google-places-api

I've looked through Google's documentation, searched a few different ways, and looked at possibly related questions on SO, but I'm not seeing a clear answer. Hoping someone here who's more familiar with the API can answer my question:

I have a user's ZIP code (U.S. postal code) and want to use this to determine their city, county, and country. Is this possible using the Google Places API? If not, what's the best way to accomplish this?

(Yes, I know ZIP implies U.S., but this may expand outside the U.S. at some point.)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4749706/lookup-city-and-state-by-zip-google-geocode-api - take your exact question and copy/paste it into google... this is the fourth result.

Comment: Crap, thanks, @Daniel.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. The Google Places API does not report the county, unfortunately. Or at least I'm not able to figure out how from their documentation.