# Error installed R library with version 3.6.0 when only version 3.4 is required

Tags: r

I´m trying to install the library ssev: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ssev/index.html

On a machine with R 3.6.0

```
install.packages("ssev")
```

And I´m getting the following error:

```
“unable to access index for repository http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/PACKAGES'”
Warning message:
“package ‘ssev’ is not available (for R version 3.6.0)”
```

What I do not understand is why I´m getting this error, when the requiered version for this library is 3.4, as shown in CRAN:

[image]

The installation does work with a more recent versions of R like 3.6.3, but in the machine I need it I do not have the option to install a newer version.

Comment: It says "warning"

Comment: @Marichyasana Yes, but is not installed. I tried with the R notebooks at kaggle.

Comment: Can you try installing each component individually. If you find one that fails copy the source to your machine.

Comment: @Marichyasana what do you mean by indiviually? there is only one libraru there

Comment: The message says that ssev installs pwr  and MESS, so install pwr and MESS first. If either of those installs others then install them too etc.

Comment: You could try to install it from github directly with `remotes::install_github("Nth-iteration-labs/ssev")`.

Comment: That looks like a temporary glitch on the cran.rstudio.com server. Try again.

Comment: Have you tried downloading the zip directly from [this page](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ssev/index.html) and installing it from RStudio GUI similar to what is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50845838/map-zip-codes-to-their-respective-city-and-state-in-r/60023266#60023266)?

Answer (score 4):

I'm using R version 3.6.1 and only getting a warning about the using the library. Generally, you can ignore these and it will still work. If it's not, try updating the package and post the results of trying to load the library and also run `version` to show info on your setup as I did below:

```
 > library(ssev)
Warning messages:
1: In recycle.data(data, FALSE, length(x), units) :
  reached elapsed time limit
2: package ‘ssev’ was built under R version 3.6.3 
> version
               _                           
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32          
arch           x86_64                      
os             mingw32                     
system         x86_64, mingw32             
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          6.1                         
year           2019                        
month          07                          
day            05                          
svn rev        76782                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
nickname       Action of the Toes
```